# Как перемножить элементы в списке на одно число Python

Tags: python, список, умножение

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(s)
```

Comment: Уважаемый @Богдан вы бы хоть удосужились прочитать все ответы  которые вам дали. И если ответы вам помогли ,  то поблагодарите тех людей которые их дали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for i in s:
    print(i*2, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBViHaUEfBSEfBWEfBREfBVEfBTEfBXEfBIpYrCSRZoWWkkJZfpFChkJmnkBjLVVCUmVeikaT5/z8A)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [x*2 for x in a]
print(b)
```

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такое решение, в функцию передается список и число, возвращает список  умноженный на число

```py
def multip_num(listt, num):
    new_list = list()
    for i in listt:
        new_list.append(i * num)

    return new_list


s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(multip_num(s, 3))
# Выведет: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое решение, с перегрузкой методов и созданием своего типа данных.

```
class NumList(list):
    def __add__(self, other):
        new_self = self.copy()
        for i in range(len(new_self)):
            if type(new_self[i]) == type(other):
                new_self[i] = new_self[i] + other
        return new_self

    def __sub__(self, other):
        new_self = self.copy()
        for i in range(len(new_self)):
            if type(new_self[i]) == type(other):
                new_self[i] = new_self[i] - other
        return new_self

    def __mul__(self, other):
        new_self = self.copy()
        for i in range(len(new_self)):
            if type(new_self[i]) == type(other):
                new_self[i] = new_self[i] * other
        return new_self


A = NumList([1, 2, 3, 4])
A.append(2)

print(A * 3)
print(A - 3)
print(A + 3)

# [3, 6, 9, 12, 6]
# [-2, -1, 0, 1, -1]
# [4, 5, 6, 7, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно с помощю библиотеки `numpy`

`pip install numpy`

```
import numpy

s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
s = numpy.array(s)

print(s * 2)
# [ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16]
```

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html